# Why google jobs search is not showing my all jobs?

Tags: google-search, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, google-index, noindex

I am facing a very weird issue to show the jobs on Google job listing. I have followed the below steps and I am still not able to see all of my jobs on Google jobs.

1. Followed correct `Job Posting` schema to build the schema structure for all my jobs.

   Link: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting
2. Verified all the job schema with `Structured Data Testing Tool - Google`. I got a valid result every time. No error and warning in the schema.

   Link: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool
3. Verified job links with the `Rich Results Test` tool. I don't see any issue there as well.

   Link: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results
4. Used the `Search Console` tool to debug into that more. I got some of the valid jobs in `Crawled - currently not indexed` status. When I checked and try to reindex those links but I can't see those jobs in the Google Jobs Search area yet. I got a success message on reindexing as well.

   Link: https://search.google.com/search-console

   Screen Shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1WYB.png
5. The sitemap gets updated on a daily basis.

As I have followed all the Google steps to take consider while developing schema, but I got no success yet. It would be great if I got answers to below questions.

1. Am I missing anything here?
2. How to avoid `Crawled - currently not indexed` excluded issue? How this functioning?
3. As you can see in the screenshot. `Crawl allowed?` is `Yes`, `Page fetch` is `Successful` and `Indexing allowed?` is `Yes` then why it is not showing in the Google Jobs search area?

Note: My site is in Wordpress. For SEO and Schema I am using Yoast SEO plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're missing anything, unless your jobs pages are undiscoverable (no internal links).

Sounds to me like you probably just need to wait. How long has it been? Google can take days to weeks for search results to "settle".

Otherwise, Google may have decided that your jobs are not important enough to show. From [the Google page you linked](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting):

> Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will show up in search results, even if your page is marked up correctly according to the [Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results). For a list of common reasons why Google may not show your structured data in search results, see the [General Structured Data Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies).

Comment: I think google jobs isn't running at the moment. For example "retail jobs in grand rapids mi" which is in the example on https://jobs.google.com/about/ doesn't show the google jobs format https://imgur.com/a/la8QHva. I've tried many other queries couldn't get the jobs format.